# How to filter table with multiple values against one field

Tags: graphql, aws-appsync

I am new to `AWS App Sync`, I want to query which accepts multiple values against one field and return result based on the input. Is this possible?

`listBookByName(bookID: [String], limit: Int, nextToken: String): listBookByNameConnection`

Answer (score 0):

You can use **DynamoDB Batch Resolvers** to accomplish this.

You would attach a resolvers to the **listBookByName** field. The request mapping template (Takes the GraphQL query and converts it to a DynamoDB query) would look like the following:

```
#set($ids = [])
#foreach($id in ${ctx.args.bookID})
    #set($map = {})
    $util.qr($map.put("id", $util.dynamodb.toString($id)))
    $util.qr($ids.add($map))
#end

{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "operation" : "BatchGetItem",
    "tables" : {
        "Books": {
            "keys": $util.toJson($ids),
            "consistentRead": true
        }
    }
}
```

Your response mapping template will then have to marshall the results into your **listBookByNameConnection** type.

Here is an example in the documentation where they have **batchGet** query which takes a list of identifiers, and returns a list of posts.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/tutorial-dynamodb-batch.html#single-table-batch

Comment: I am getting null as result. seems i am missing some configuration. Could you please help

Comment: Your response mapping template is returning a list of book objects. However, your output type is a listBookByNameConnections object which an attribute "items", which is a list of books. You can try changing your output type of listBookByName to just be [Books], then your response mapping template should work.

Comment: Also, you can enable logging for AppSync to help you debug. 

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/monitoring.html#cwl

Answer (score 0):

I have configured the setting as mentioned in the link. but it is returning null all the time.

```
type Query {
listBookByName(bookID: [String], limit: Int, nextToken: String): istBookByNameConnections
}

type listBookByNameConnections {
    items: [Books]
}
```

My Resolver Mapping:

```
#set($ids = [])
#foreach($id in ${ctx.args.bookID})
    #set($map = {})
    $util.qr($map.put("id", $util.dynamodb.toString($id)))
    $util.qr($ids.add($map))
#end

{
    "version" : "2018-05-29",
    "operation" : "BatchGetItem",
    "tables" : {
        "Books": {
            "keys": $util.toJson($ids),
            "consistentRead": true
        }
    }
}
```

Response Mapping:

```
$util.toJson($ctx.result.data.Books)
```

Query i used to check the response:

```
query get {
    listBookByName(bookID:["JAVA","JUNIT"]){
    items{
      name
    }
    }
}
```

output :
 {
   "data": {
       "listDriverTripsByName": null
      }
    }